# Find the antiderivative for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Evaluate $\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+\cos^2t}$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

I got this question in an analysis exam, and I did what everybody does ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244055/integrate-frac11-cos2x-probably-need-using-some-trigonometric-identity)), I made $u=\tan t$ and I got $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt2}\right)$ but I know this is wrong because $\tan x$ is not continuous in every $[0,x]$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638025/definite-integration-problem/638035#638035) it's solved until $\pi$, but my limit is $x$ so I'm not sure what should I do.

Also, we have the integral of a positive amount, so my answer should be an increasing function...

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170885/a-little-integration-paradox) is explained why this happens (which I already know), and the answers there don't solve the integral between $0$ and $x$. One answer gives a possible result (that have to be adapted, since there it is indefinite), but no deduction of it. The answer given here is much more complete and perfectly address my specific question.

Comment: you may look at the different branches of arctan carefully to get a sensible answer.

Comment: So I could divide $[0,x]$ in several intervals where the substitution is not sinful and then put my answer in term of $n$ intervals I may have? Or is that an ugly solution?

Comment: look at the answer given, it is excellent!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac1{1+\cos^2(t)} = \dfrac{\sec^2(t)}{\sec^2(t)+1} = \dfrac{\sec^2(t)}{2+\tan^2(t)}$$
This gives us
$$I(x) = \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+\cos^2(t)} = \int_0^x \dfrac{\sec^2(t)}{2+\tan^2(t)}dt$$
Setting $y=\tan(t)$, we have
$$I(x) = \int_0^{\tan(x)} \dfrac{dy}{2+y^2} = \left.\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt2}\right) \right\vert_0^{\tan(x)} = \dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
This is valid for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$. For $x>\pi/2$, express $x$ as $n\pi+y$, where $y \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, we then have
$$I(x) = \dfrac{n\pi}{\sqrt2}+\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\tan(y)}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
Hence, $I(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Comment: i don't think the answer is right. what you need is $I(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+\cos^2 t} = 2I(\pi/2) + I(\pi - x), \pi/2< x < \pi$  then $I(x)  = int(x,\pi)I(\pi)  + I(x - \pi(int(x/\pi)) $

Comment: @abel Thanks. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Isn't $\tan \pi/2$ (and also $\tan -\pi/2$) undefined?